# How do you insert a row into a null table with auto incrementing ID?

Tags: sql, insert, increment, auto-increment

I want to insert a row with an auto-incrementing uid into a table that is null. With the following code I am getting an error because you cannot +1 a null value (for [TABLE_UID]). I have tried adding `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` but it is not valid syntax.

```
cmdEx.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME]([TABLE_UID], KIP_UID, NEXT_DATE, STUT_UID, CS_DATE, CE_DATE, S_M, PG_A) VALUES ((SELECT MAX([TABLE_UID]) + 1 FROM [TABLE_NAME]), '127', '2009-06-15T13:45:30', '0', '2009-06-15T13:45:30','2010-06-15T13:45:30', 'boom', 0 )");
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  For some of them, inserting the first row in an empty table causes autoincrement to generate the value 1, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NVL or coalesce function and assign value as 0 when col is null.

```
Query1 - 
with t1 as (select null as col1) select max(col1) + 1 from t1;

o/p
NULL

Query 2 -
with t1 as (select null as col1) select nvl(max(col1),0) + 1 from t1;

o/p
1
```

Comment: There is no way to do this directly inside an insert statement? The answer you gave is definitely what I am looking for but I am not sure how to get it to work in coordination with the above insert statement from a C# interface.

Comment: You can do it in insert statement as well, add nvl function to select clause  - SELECT MAX(NVL(PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE_UID),0) + 1 FROM PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work, but this did: (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE_UID), 0)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was:

```
cmdEx.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE (PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE_UID, USER_UID, SCHEDULED_DATE, PMS_CALC_STATUS_UID, CALCULATION_START_DATE, CALCULATION_END_DATE, STATUS_MESSAGE, PROGRESS) VALUES ((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE_UID), 0) + 1 FROM PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE), 127, '2009-06-15T13:45:30', 0, '2009-06-15T13:45:30','2010-06-15T13:45:30', 'TEST DELETE THIS ROW', 0 )"); //(SELECT MAX(PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE_UID) + 1 FROM PMS_CALC_SCHEDULE)
```